# Bower won't install globally on OS X

Tags: installation, npm, bower

I'm on OS X 10.8.5, running node 0.10.11 and npm 1.2.30.  Trying to globally install bower with this command:

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

But I'm consistently getting this in my `npm-debug.log`:

```
2872 error Error: ENOENT, lstat 

'/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js'
2873 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
2873 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
2873 error or email it to:
2873 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
2874 error System Darwin 12.5.0
2875 error command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.11/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
2876 error cwd /Users/kdbanman
2877 error node -v v0.10.11
2878 error npm -v 1.2.30
2879 error path /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js
2880 error fstream_path /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js
2881 error fstream_type File
2882 error fstream_class FileWriter
2883 error code ENOENT
2884 error errno 34
2885 error fstream_stack /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.11/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
2885 error fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

> *If I get a solution from the mailing list, I'll post it here.  I just
>   want to make sure that discussion ends up an stackoverflow because
>   people will find it easier than if it were on a github issues page or*
>   a mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me without the sudo command.

```
$ npm install -g bower
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Which version of OSX, npm, and bower are you working with?

Comment: OSX Version 10.10.5
$ npm -v
2.12.1
$ bower -v
1.5.2

Comment: That differs by major, minor, and revision versions across the board, so I'm not very surprised your behavior is different.

Comment: ah, now that I actually read your post, I see my answer is not very useful. sorry 'bout that chief!